# One connector pin connected to TX (or RX) and DP (or DM) of STM32 microcontroller

Tags: usb, stm32, uart

I have a project here that needs the STM32L432 to operate in two modes, UART and USB. It will be connected to another system via a 5 (or 4) pin connector. It operates mainly in UART mode with pins configured to 3V3, TX, RX and GND. Sometimes it needs be connected to a computer via USB-Adapter with pins configured to 5V, DP, DM, GND. Basically saying, my product needs to detect the change and change firmware operation rom UART > USB or USB > UART from unplugging and plugging the system.

My questions are...

- What are some tips and tricks that can make this possible?
- Is it ok when I just connect TX/RX with DP/DM? Are extra circuitries needed here?
  I am open to adding other components to the project and using GPIO input pins etc.

Here are some of my ideas but not sure which is do-able...

- Use LDO that can detect a higher input voltage (if such component exists) + GPIO Input
- Build circuit that detects higher input voltage + GPIO Input
- Somehow make use of the 5th Pin of connector?

[image: STM32 in UART and USB Mode]

Comment: USB is differential and bidirectional. Connecting one leg to an output pin is definitely going to stop it working.